# What can image only web analytics track?

Tags: image, analytics, web-analytics

I know that image only web analytics can track visits, but is that all it can track?  Can it track unique visitors or anything more than plain visits?  Let's say I'm a third party trying to put html only analytics on a site like, say, myspace.  What exactly would I be able to track?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It'll still be able to track uniques somewhat, via repeat visits from the same IP/user agent. User agent (browser, OS, etc.) can be picked up, and the site may pass other information (like user ID, referring URL, stuff like that) in the image's URL as variables.

Comment: Let's say I'm a third party trying to put html only analytics on a site like, say, myspace.  Would all that info (user id, referring url, etc) still be available?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be available, unless MySpace gave you some sort of templating language that made user ID and referrer available.